# Ubuntu Server Run Script at Login for Specific User

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a python program I want to run when a specific user logs into my Ubuntu Server. Previously, I tried to do this via the command `useradd -m -s /var/jumpbox/jumpbox.py jumpbox`. This ran the program, but it didn't work the same way it did when I call it via `./jumpbox.py` from the `/var/jumpbox` directory. The problem is, this is a curses menu and when an option is selected, another `.py` file is called to run. Using the `useradd` method to run `jumpbox.py`, my menu was the part the worked, but it never called my other `.py` files when an option was selected. What is the best way to go about running my `/var/jumpbox/jumpbox.py` file is run when the `jumpbox` user (and only this user) logs into the server?

Comment: Could it be that your script, when executing the second script, does not have full path applied to it, or it includes something and your PYTHONPATH is wrong? Does it work if you do cd /tmp;/var/jumpbox/jumpbox.py?  If not, then it is a path issue. Exactly how to solve it depends on your code, but if there is a call to execute something, just add full path there and it should do the trick. If it is an include problem, you can use sys.path.insert(0, "/var/jumpbox") and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It was the path of the `.py` file being called inside `jumpbox.py`. I was referencing it only as the filename, without the full path, since it was in the same directory. `os.system("python <full path>.py")` made it work perfectly.

Thanks @Hannu